# There is a gap in my control in canvas when I scroll the scrollview

Tags: wpf, path, scrollview

```
<Canvas DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Path Data="{Binding PathGeometry}" 
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
          StrokeDashArray="{Binding StrokeDashArray}"
          StrokeEndLineCap="Flat"
          StrokeLineJoin="Miter"
          StrokeMiterLimit="10"
          StrokeStartLineCap="Flat"
          StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThikness}"/>
    <Path Data="{Binding PathGeometry}"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          Stroke="Transparent"
          StrokeThickness="8" />
```

When I scroll the scroll to bottom, the path's height will be heigher, but the property value is not changed.

Comment: The code is incomplete. The Canvas has no closing tag, the ScrollViewer is missing, and the Path Data is not provided either. You need to give all the code that others can use to recreate the issue.

Comment: Many thanks for you.and now found its not the path's problem. but I have a question here, and I set the path's strokeThickness as "1",but I get the path's actualHeight is "0.5" from Snoop.Why the ActualHeight is half of StrokeThickness.